# hide border if there is no content

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

On a div I have css set:

```
div.class {border: 1px solid red;}
```

The div is positioned absolutely in the center of the page. The problem is that the border appears even if there is no content.

Any css methods to get the border to not appear if there is no content?

Comment: Seems semantically iffy to have a div with no content. Is it possible for you to only write the div to the page when content is available?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

**CSS3** has a selector defined for this case. It does not work in IE8 and lower though.

```
div.class:empty { 
    border: none;
}
```

**Your best option** would be to tweak this on the **server side**, and simply don't display that div if it would be empty.

Comment: @Ascherer Would work, but it is certainly not the best practice in this situation.

Comment: depends on what the situation actually is

Comment: This can also be combined with :not

Comment: Doesn't work inside a web component on a named slot

Answer (score 0):

If the div can have content related to a server response, you can tell whether it is an empty or a filled response and change to display:none or display:block accordingly